# Применение мультиметода и его реализация на С++11 с использованием RTTI

Tags: c++, ооп, c++11, полиморфизм, rtti

Столкнулся со сложной задачей, решение которой мне не поддаётся уже второй день.  
Ниже будет краткое описание задачи, **решение которой я прошу оставить за мной**.

**Вопросы:**

**1.** Как проверить наличие хранящиейся реализации мультиметодов в данном случае?  
**2.** Возможно ли решение данной задачи моим способом? Если нет, то как грамотно организовать алгоритм решения этой задачи?   
**3.** Верно ли тут использование map?  
**4.** Как грамотно пробежать по всем значениям first в map для сравнения с std::pair и вызывать хранящуюся в map ф-ю через указатель на неё с параметрами из этого самого std::pair?   
**5.** Прошу указать на мои ошибки и объяснить как правильно

```
addImpl — добавляет реализацию мультиметода для двух типов, которые заданы через std::type_info.
hasImpl — принимает два указателя и проверяет, есть ли реализация мультиметода для соответствующих типов.
call — принимает два указателя и вызывает для них соответствующую реализацию.
```

*Реализация этих методов должна корректно обрабатывать ситуацию, когда мультиметод является коммутативным

```
// Base - базовый класс иерархии
// Result - тип возвращаемого значения мультиметода
// Commutative - флаг, который показывает, что
// мультиметод коммутативный (т.е. f(x,y) = f(y,x)).
    template<class Base, class Result, bool Commutative>
    struct Multimethod2
    {
        // устанавливает реализацию мультиметода
        // для типов t1 и t2 заданных через typeid 
        // f - это функция или функциональный объект
        // принимающий два указателя на Base 
        // и возвращающий значение типа Result
        void addImpl( ... t1, ... t2, ... f )
        {
        }
        // проверяет, есть ли реализация мультиметода
        // для типов объектов a и b
        bool hasImpl(Base * a, Base * b) const
        {
            // возвращает true, если реализация есть
            // если операция коммутативная, то нужно 
            // проверить есть ли реализация для b и а 
            return ...; 
        }

        // Применяет мультиметод к объектам
        // по указателям a и b
        Result call(Base * a, Base * b) const
        {
            // возвращает результат применения реализации
            // мультиметода к a и b
            return ...;
        }
    };
```

**Далее мои рассуждения.**  
1. Для хранения реализации мультиметода будем использовать приватное поле данного класса. Это будет map с парой type_index и указателем на ф-ю, который реализован через std::function

```
  using FunFObj = std::function <Result(Base*, Base*)>;
    private:
        std::map< std::pair<std::type_index, std::type_index>, FunFObj > MultData;
    };
```

2. Добавление реализуем для двух случаев

```
    void addImpl(std::type_info const & t1, std::type_info const & t2,
                                                                FunFObj f)
        {
            if (!Commutative) MultData.insert(std::make_pair<t1, t2>, f);
            if (Commutative)
            {
                MultData.insert(std::make_pair<t2, t1>, f);
                MultData.insert(std::make_pair<t1, t2>, f);
            }
        }
```

3. А вот как сравнивать std::pair из map с данными в hasimpl и call я не знаю.

Comment: для std::type_info определены операторы равно-неравно, так что это не должно быть проблемой проверить на равенство, но вот больше-меньше - у вас не получится... точнее можно определить какой-нибудь хитрожопый оператор, но это логически противоречиво: как может один тип быть больше другого. Для такого случая замените map списком.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а зачем больше-меньше? Цель сравнить на равно-неравно объекты из хранящегося std::pair (там лежат два std::type_info) c полученными двумя typeid(a) и typeid(b) типа Base*.


(it->first == PairThis) return it->second(a,b);
Что-то типа этого, но такая конструкция не работает

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch: Что значит "больше-меньше не получится"? Специально для больше-меньше у `type_info` есть метод `before`. Другое дело, что больше-меньше тут не нужно.

Comment: @AnT вопрошающий хочет использовать `type_info` (пары из них) в `map`, а для него, как раз таки, это нужно (по крайней мере по умолчанию `less` если не задана другая функция сравнения).

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Прекрасно. Так вот для реализации упорядочивающего сравнения есть метод `before`, который упорядочивает все `type_info`. Т.е. никаких сложностей с этим нет - сравнивайте на здоровье.

Comment: @AnT Вы сказали что ненужны, я же ответил почему они нужны и ничего не писал, о том, что их нельзя сделать. Более того, я как раз таки написал, что можно их определить, но в детали не вдавался.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Мой комментарий является ответом на следующее ваше утверждение: "**больше-меньше - у вас не получится**... точнее можно определить какой-нибудь хитрожопый оператор, но это логически противоречиво: **как может один тип быть больше другого**". (выделение мое). Все. Больше я ничего сказать не хотел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думал оставить комментарий, но потом решил, что это тянет на ответ (ну или по-крайней мере его часть).

Начну с четвертого пункта:

По `map` не нужно `бегать` - это бинарное дерево поиска, так что, если вам нужно найти `value` которое храниться в `map` по `key`, то вы можете сделать так:

```
auto any_value = some_map[key];
```

Дерево реализовано так, что независимо от количества хранимых данных это всегда будет иметь логарифмическую сложность. Правда способ, которым я получил `value` годиться только в том случае, если вы точно уверены, что оно там есть, так как если его нет, то оно будет создано с помощью конструктора по умолчанию. Если вас это не устраивает, то используйте

```
some_map.at(key);
```

Правда учтите, что если `key` отсутствует, то вы получите исключение `out_of_range`, так что оберните в `try-catch`. Но вообще, лучше использовать `find` - дело в том, что эта операция почти так же быстра как и предыдущие, но в этом случае вы независите от того, какой контейнер вы будете использовать (вы можете заменить на список и даже не заметить разницы, если только не работаете с большими объемами данных).

Теперь к 3:
Нет, не верно. Во-первых стоит начать, с того, что `map` упорядочивает элементы (по умолчанию) с помощью оператора `<`, а это означает, что ключи должны поддерживать эту операцию (можно также использовать и свою собственную операцию, но это другая история). Вы же используете `std::type_info` который имеет операторы `==` & `!=`. Можно, конечно определить хитрожопые операторы сравнения для этого типа, но это нелогично (как один тип может быть больше другого), так что вам лучше использовать не `map` а список. По крайней мере для таких "ключей". Если же решите использовать другие ключи, то если они будут поддерживать операцию сравнения, то можно использовать и `map` (при этом если вы правильно использовали список, то замена его на `map` - дело изменения `std::list` на `std::map` при инициализации).

1) Реализация, если я правильно понял, это `std::function`, а для нее определены операторы равно-неравно, но вот меньше-больше - нет. Но в любом случае, это будет хранить как `value` так что они и не нужны.

Вообщем задумка верная, по-крайней мере я бы делал похожим образом.

UDP

Как я глянул у `type_info` есть `hash_code`, и это наталкивает на мысль, что сдесь можно использовать `std::unorder_map` - не даром же этот контейнер ввели.

UDP

В связи с обновлением первого пункта. Сдесь все должно быть довольно просто: если вам нужно проверить наличие `value` для ключа `key`, то просто попытайтесь найти `key`

```
 if (som_kont.find(key) != som_kont.end()) {
    // founded
 } else {
    // not founded
 }
```

Comment: Да, реализация мультиметода хранится действительно в std::function. Только вот зачем именно реализацию сравнивать? Мы либо добавляем эту реализацию в 1 методе, либо во 2 методе ищем соответствующие пары для переданных типов, либо вызываем хранимый мультиметод из 3 метода.

Comment: @AlexIdest ну так Вы задавали вопрос (1 пункт) или нет? Или Вы может опечатались, что ли?

Comment: Вы совершенно правы. Моя оплошность, нужно было написать "Как проверить наличие реализации", а не "как сравнить". Сейчас исправлю